# Can induced emf reverse direction of current in a circuit?

Tags: thought-experiment

Suppose that my increase in the current is so high that emf developed across inductor just exceeds the potential difference across the battery in LR circuit .So can the direction of current be against the battery?

Comment: Not in a static way with a battery. The EMF builds up gradually and weakens the voltage that the battery has to drive the current through the inductor. But with an LC resonating circuit and you are able to eventually reverse the direction in some way.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible! The current stops flowing as soon as the EMF developed across the inductor becomes equal to the EMF of the cell/battery. Remember that the cell's EMF provides for the driving force which makes electrons (or conventionally, positive charge) flow upto the capacitor's plates, through the circuit. But gradually charges start accumulating at it's plates and start opposing the upcoming charges. When this opposing potential difference becomes equal to the EMF of the cell, the current flow stops.